Why are outward-opening doors heavier than plug-type door in a plane?
I saw on LinkedIn:

Why are outward-opening doors heavier than plug-type door in a plane?

Both of those are plug-type doors, so I wouldn't be too confident in the credibility of this source. The Airbus design might be heavier though...

The source is nonsense. It might be more AI drivel. The Airbus door does not rely on mechanical locks, it too relies on air pressure. Boeings do have assist unless it's a 737. I too believe the Airbus style can be heavier due to load being concentrated at the door stops.

@Bianfable, "Both of those are plug-type doors..." Huh?  They both open outward, not inward... what am I missing here?

They both open outward and are plug-type. The exact motion is a bit more elaborate. Some details are in this answer, including links to videos showing the mechanism in more detail.

@Bianfable The reference calls the A321 a plug door but it is not. It has pins that slide into catches as the door drops into its sealed position from the outside. In contrast, the Boeing door tilts and angles so as to enter the fuselage then reorients itself to close from the inside. Pressure tries to open the Airbus door, working against the pins where pressure forces the Boeing door tighter into the frame.

There is nothing wrong with this question other than the table says a plug door is the heavier, which is backwards. Bianfable's reference shows the operation of the airbus door. Contrast that with this Boeing video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxzLNBlDVbE

Plug type:
Self sealing door. The cabin pressure forces the door into the fuselage. As long as the door is larger than the opening (with proper shape and strength) only minimal hardware is required to keep it from becoming dislodged.
Outward opening:
Not "self sealing". Additional hardware and fortifications are required to keep the door from busting open.
Note:
If your airline is pressurized to the equivalent of about 8000 ft altitude, the pressure differential is 4.2 PSI for an aircraft at 36,000 ft (10.9 - 6.7). I don't know how big an airline door is, but this equals about 600 lbs force per square foot. This force is mostly concentrated on the hardware used to hold the door on, hence a lot of fortification is required.

The doors in the question's picture are both plug type and both open outward... And they are neither castles needing fortifications  Is this an AI generated answer?

Still a valid question even if they picked a bad picture. What makes you think this is AI generated?

All questions are legitimate  But this question is asked like if outward opening doors and plug doors were mutually exclusive which is not the case. It also refers to a link and a picture which are confusing as well.

The wording from Part 25.783 is "initial opening movement is [not] inward." The Airbus style door has an initial opening movement that is inward, and thus is "self sealing." Most hinged airstair doors on regionals and even many outward bulk cargo doors, meet this opening inwards requirement.

@user71659 The Airbus door is not a plug door and you misinterpret its initial movement. It is held in place by pins and seals on the outside. If the pins break the door will fly off. The characteristic of a plug door is that it jams itself into the fuselage frame, and the wall of the aircraft has to break before it will fly off. This is a reasonable answer.

@sophit It seems reasonable that fortification means reinforcement. The A321 door is not a plug door, regardless of the description. Look at its operation. This answer is correct.

@Pilothead Incorrect, I suggest you review how the Airbus door works. The door stop rollers fit in tracks that are shaped like a 7. This means the door has to go back before it can lift up and clear the roller track and static stops. You also need to read my comment carefully. I never claimed it was a plug door, nor does Part 25 say anything about plug doors, only the initial movement of the door.

@user71659 This whole question is about plug doors and whether or not they are heavier than non-plug doors, labeled outward opening. If you are arguing that the label is not sufficiently descriptive, then ok. Arguing that any door with initial inward movement is self sealing is not correct. It only means that the latching mechanism has over center like operation. If the latch breaks, the door still comes off, ie. not sealed. The presence of latches (or not) and the required reinforcement to make them work is the difference between the categories of door, and the essence of the question.

@Pilothead: both doors are subject to more or less the same pressurisation load. Boeing's door download that load via its "wider than the hole" sides pushing against the fuselage frame; Airbus's door download that load via rollers/pins also pushing against the fuselage frame. Being both systems sized by the same load, that all the pins on the Airbus's door will break is as probable as that the "wider than the hole" sides of Boeing's door will break. I wouldn't expect one design to be more complex, heavier, safer or cheaper than the other one but I agree that the terminology is misleading.

@sophit I admit I don't know exactly how Boeing's "wider than the hole" door is designed, but it could potentially distribute the load around the entire perimeter of the door. The airbus door, using pins, has far less surface area to distribute this same load. Since pressure = force / area the Boeing door could potentially get away with FAR less fortification.

@codenoob: Yes, the fuselage frame around the door of an Airbus might be reinforced where the pins engage but the rest of the structure might be built thinner so that saying that globally one design is lighter than the other is a bit difficult.
